# How do I change my pygame window coordinates of (0,0) from top left to bottom left?

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates, python-3.8

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode((850, 600))
```

How can I modify or augment the code above to convert the origin from being at top left to bottom left?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
w = 600
h = 700
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
print(w,h,ws,hs)
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))
```